# using the chronology package with babel french option

Tags: babel, french, chronology

I'm trying to use the chronology package and it works fine with the english option in the babel package but if I use

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

It doesn't work anymore. I've found a solution (that I don't understand) on a french forum. It says I can use

```
\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
```

It works fine with a simple example like this :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\begin{chronology}[5]{1983}{2010}{10cm}[7cm]
\event{1984}{\color{blue}{one}}
\event[1985]{1986}{\small{two}}
\event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{\huge{three}}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Yet my text throw an exception :

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalablefonts.\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox\fi \fi \chapter
```

on this line :

```
\chapter{Environnement de travail}
```

I'm fairly new to Latex and I guess that a encoding problem with the font but I have no idea about the solution.

**EDIT** :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\title{test}

\begin{document}
\chapter{L'environnement de travail}
\section{Le groupe}
\subsection{Historique}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{chronology}[5]{1964}{2012}{20cm}[10cm]
\event{1864}{Création}
\end{chronology}
\vspace{1cm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In mollis odio tortor, a ultrices neque posuere vitae. Aenean nec arcu nec lorem luctus dictum.

\end{document}
```

This doesn't work. But if I delete the lorem ipsum It works fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We will need to see an example like the one you posted that actually reproduces the error. I don't see that it is related to either `french` or `chronology` but only an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) will tell...

Comment: Your edited MWE compiles just fine for me, i.e., it doesn't give the error you describe. (The picture is too large but you've set the width manually to `20cm` which is more than `\textwidth` and the `\event` is out of the range, but I guess you didn't mean that?)

Comment: Install the cm-super package (large). If this doesn't help, remove microtype, compile with pdflatex and show the end of the log-file (where all the fonts are listed).

Comment: I didn't mean that. I've changed to 10cm and the warning disappeared but it still doesn't want to compile. How the environment can change it ?  
I'm using windows with Miktek 2.9 and texmaker.

Comment: @Thibaut The problem is surely due to not having a Type1 version for the CM fonts in the T1 encoding; either install the CM-Super package or add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: @egreg \usepackage{lmodern} is not working and I don't know why but I can't download the CM-Super package through the mikteX packet manager and I can't find the package online. I will check this at home.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works well with the cm-package, but I had to let the microtype line. Put it as a answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the cm-super package (large).

If this doesn't help: remove `microtype` (to be able to see in the log file the fonts used), compile with pdflatex and show the end of the `log`-file (where all the fonts are listed).